# How to get correct number?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, while-loop, user-input

--Python
What's wrong in this code?

```
a=int(input('enter a number'))
b=list(range(1,11))
if a not in b:
   int(input('enter a number'))
else :
   print('ok')
```

output:

```
 enter a number 89
 enter a number 8
```

Comment: `int(input('enter a number'))` _by itself_ (in the `if` body) just throws away that integer. Did you mean `a = int(input('enter a number'))`?

Comment: after else its not printing Ok

Comment: that's because it never gets to the `else` part since if you enter 89, then `a = 89`, so `a not in range(1, 11)` is true, so it asks you for input, throws the result away (because you never assign it to anything) and exits the script. Did you mean to write a `while` loop instead of an `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please explain a bit further what it is you're trying to do, if you're trying to output "OK" for the second input of '8', then you need to change the logic of this code.

> a=int(input('enter a number'))

this line prints "enter a number"
then your if statement checks if its within b
but if it's not it prints "enter a number" again without doing anything with it, as seen in the next line:

> int(input('enter a number'))

try using a for loop or while loop if you want your code to run through the if-else blocks more than once.

- also, notice that you didn't put the input inside variable a again.

EDIT: try this code:

```
    print('enter a number')
a=int(input())
while a not in range(1,11):
    print('enter a number')
    a=int(input())
else :
   print('ok')
```